# find length of unsafe byte* pointing to native byte array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, native

How can I find the length of byte* in c#?

It's pointing to a native byte array in an unmanaged c++ library. I need to convert it to a c# byte[], but in order to do so, I need the length. .Length doesn't work.

```
byte* ETC = //Stuff from unmanaged c++ DLL;
int ETCLength = ????
```

Comment: Well, this is why arrays in the C language are a broken abstraction.  It is *just* a pointer, it only stores an address and doesn't know means about the object it points to.  Clearly you need to show us the unmanaged api you are using to get a better answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *cannot* know the length of something just from a pointer; the pointer is **just** the start. Usually, a pointer and a length are passed *together*. In the future, this may be improved by [`Span<T>`](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2017/04/spans-and-ref-part-2-spans.html) - or maybe it won't! Time will tell.

You need to already know the length. This could be via an API, or it could be via documentation. There *may* be a pattern to the data that implies the end (`nul` terminators, for example, or the length being encoded in the first few bytes), but: that approach is how most buffer attacks start. You should *always* know the length if you're talking about pointers.